# Storing BMP in icon file

Tags: c#, icons, file-format

I have a program to combine graphics files in an icon.  Sizes include 16,24,32,48,256 32bit.  These use PNG and works.  I have correct header and directory/index record list.

However, for 8 bit I am using BMP with the first 14 bytes of the header of a BMP stripped off.  This part of the icon file does not work.  Having looked at a MS icon they have BMP stored again with the 14 byte header removed.  Looking at their BMP data they have the second header as I do but for 16x16 the second header (BITMAPINFOHEADER) says 16x32.  The BMP seams to be twice the width.  Why?  Is the image twice the width with a bit mask or something?

Here's my code: (Note image is 32x32 bitmap 32bit when passed.)

```
using (Bitmap imageAsBitmap = new Bitmap(image))
{
    int colorCount = 0;
    using (Bitmap bitmap = imageAsBitmap.ColourReduction256(out colorCount))
    {
        byte[] imageBytes = new byte[] { };
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bitmap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
            imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
        }
        byte[] data = new byte[] { };
        Array.Resize(ref data, imageBytes.Length - 14);
        Array.Copy(imageBytes, 14, data, 0, data.Length);
        enteries.Add(new IconEntry(data, image.Width, image.Height, 8));
    }
}
```

Comment: The `Array.Resize` seems unnecessary. You can just declare data as `new byte[imageBytes.Length - 14]`.

Comment: @Abion47 Try it's a bit of a habit because I have done lots of comms where size is not known but in this case yes.  I might mod that part to make it more readable.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right:

> Images with less than 32 bits of color depth follow a particular
>   format: the image is encoded as a single image consisting of a color
>   mask (the "XOR mask") together with an opacity mask (the "AND mask")[..]

What results in:

> [..] the masks must each be of the same dimensions, and the height
>   specified in the BMP header must be exactly twice the height specified
>   in the ICONDIRENTRY structure

Take a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format)

Comment: Thanks.  I don't surpose you know how to add the XOR mask to a Bitmap object do you?  It's 1bpp where as the image it's self is 8bpp.

Comment: All sorted now! Phew!

Comment: I did: Own DIB header with double height, add bitmap palette and color array and then mask which is basically 1 bit per pixel raw data (padded) as per calc on web page.